# Remove and replace value of JSON using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am creating a heatmap in highChart. I am getting my response like `datajson` from a web socket. How do I make a heatmap from this json?

```
var datajson = [
    {"type":"a","symbol":"GOO","price":"385.7110"},
    {"type":"a","symbol":"ORCl","price":"444.711"},
    {"type":"b","symbol":"GOO","price":"555.711"}
]
```

I need to get

```
var datajson = [
    [0,0,385.7110],
    [0,1,444.711],
    [1,0,555.711]
]
```

Comment: You need to give some kind of indication of what the difference is; ie, what are the 0s and 1s in relation to the first object?

Comment: The result you are wanting is invalid `[{0,0,385.7110}]` do you mean `[[0,0,385.7110]]`

Comment: Is Java *or* jquery actually relevant to your question? **How**?

Comment: is jquery question

Comment: yes dear!! @synthet1c u are right,, i have edited my question

Answer (score 0):

You have not said why you are setting the 1's and 0's in the array, so there is no way for me to guess. but here is a way using `Array.prototype.map` to iterate over the array, modify it and get a new array back.

```js
var datajson = [
  {"type":"a","symbol":"GOO","price":"385.7110"},
  {"type":"a","symbol":"ORCl","price":"444.711"},
  {"type":"b","symbol":"GOO","price":"555.711"}
]

// map over the datajson array returning a new array
var result = datajson.map(item => [
  item.type === 'a' ? 0 : 1,
  item.symbol === 'GOO' ? 0 : 1,
  item.price
])
    
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var replace = function(data) {
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (data[i].type === "a") {
      data[i].type = "0";
    } else {
      data[i].type = "1";
    }

    if (data[i].symbol === "GOO") {
      data[i].symbol = "0";
    } else { 
      data[i].symbol = "1";
    }
  }
};          

var datajson = [{"type":"a","symbol":"GOO","price":"385.7110"}, 
                {"type":"a","symbol":"ORCl","price":"444.711"}, 
                {"type":"b","symbol":"GOO","price":"555.711"}];

replace(datajson);
```